# Weight-Paint Brushes or Blend Keymap?

Tags: weight-painting, shortcut

In 2.9x, on Linux, I have no keymap for selecting brushes in Weight-Paint.. a while back, it was the keyboard numbers, I thought. But not now. Is this a shared experience, or have I overridden it somehow?

Is there a way to revive the shortcuts in preferences? I don't know how I'd find the operator name, if there is one. Alternatively, a keymap for flipping between 'Add' and 'Subtract' Blend modes would help.